# Filtering select with join on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I got a table named **entity** that has the following columns:
***id*** | ***flag*** | ***foreignKey*** | ***parentEntityId***

Misc notes

- None of those fields can be NULL
- When ***parentEntityId*** !=0 you can be sure that ***foreignKey*** also has a value !=0 (and vice-versa)

I had to gather some data with the following constraints :

- ***foreignKey*** has to be equal to 0  [easy `:D`]
- ***flag*** must be equal to 0 OR (let's say 15) [easy `:p`]
- ***id*** must not be referenced on another row's ***parentEntityId*** field [ `:/` ?]

> I did not manage to satisfy the last constraint using self join

```
-- I Finally ended up with a sub-query (which returns what I need) :
SELECT e.*
FROM entity e
WHERE e.flag='15'
 -- gathering entities ids where foreignKey has a specific value
 AND e.id NOT IN
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONVERT(parentId , CHAR(8)) SEPARATOR ",")
     FROM entity where foreignKey='10'
     GROUP BY id
  );
```

My question is .. Can this be achieved with a "self join" expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (for the conditions in the text):

```
select e.*
from entity e
where e.foreignKey = 0 and
      e.flag in (0, 15) and
      not exists (select 1 from entity e2 where e2.parentid = e.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your self-join method, also called an anti-join in this case:

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM entity e1
LEFT JOIN entity e2
  ON e2.parentEntityId = e1.id
WHERE e1.flag = 15
  AND e1.foreignKey = 0
  AND e2.id IS NULL
```

You don't need to worry about how many records have a matching `parentEntityId` because it's an anti-join (you're excluding any record that has a match).

Answer (score 0):

I think you make it too complicated.
Why don't you use such a simple query?

```
SELECT e.*
FROM entity e
WHERE e.flag='15'
 AND e.parentEntityId NOT IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM entity e
  );
```

You filter off all the children entities this way.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of performance hit this would take, but strictly speaking, putting a distinct in a `not in` is useless.  The not in will exclude the id only once no matter how many times its in the subselect.